# How to clone a collection from one MongoDB to another on same server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, clone

I'm using Mongo 3.2. I have two databases on my localhost named **client1** and **client2**.
Now **client1** contains a collection named **users**.
I want to clone this collection to **client2**.

I have tried:-

> use client2
>
> db.cloneCollection('localhost:27017', 'client1.users',
>                       { 'active' : true } )

This outputs

> {
>       "ok" : 0.0,
>       "errmsg" : "can't cloneCollection from self"
>   }

Is cloning a collection from one db to another on the same server prohibited?

Answer (score 2):

Few things :

1. In general [cloneCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) is used for different mongo instances but not to copy on same instances.
2. Also if you're using `v4.2` you should stop using `copyDB` & `cloneCollection` cause they're deprecated [compatibility-with-v4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#deprecate-support-for-clonecollection?searchProperty=current&query=mo) & start using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) or [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html) & [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoimport/).
3. I would suggest to use **mongodump** & **mongorestore** :

   1. Cause **mongodump** would preserve MongoDB's data types i.e.; `bson` types.
   2. **mongodump** creates a binary where as **mongoexport** would convert `bson` to `json` & again **mongoimport** will convert `json` to `bson` while writing, which is why they're slow. You can use mongoexport & mongoimport when you wanted to analyze your collections data visually or use `json` data for any other purpose.
4. You can run below script in shell

   ```
   declare - a collections = ("collectionName1" "collectionName2")
   for i in "${collections[@]}"
   do
   echo "$i"
       mongodump --host "All-shards" --username=uname --password password --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname --collection "$i"

       mongorestore --host=host-shard-name --port=27017 --username=uname --password=psswrd --ssl --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=dbname --collection= "$i" ./dump/dbName/"$i".bson;
   done
   ```

To use **mongodump**, you must run mongodump against a running mongod or mongos instance. So these commands are being run expecting mongo is properly installed & path setup is good, if not you can navigate to mongo folder & run like `./mongodump` & `./mongorestore`. Above script will be useful if you wanted to backup multiple collections, You need specify few things in script like :

1. `mongodump--host "All-shards"` -> Here you need to specify all shards if your MongoDB is a replica set, if not you can specify `localhost:27017`.
2. `mongorestore --host=host-shard-name` -> You've to specify one shard of replica set, else your `localhost`, Few things here can be optional `--ssl`, `--username`, `--password`.
3. So **mongodump** will create a folder named **dump** for first time which will have the sub-folders with dbNames & each sub-folder will has `bson` files respective to their collection names dumped, So you need to refer `dbName` in restore command & collection name will be taken from variable `i` -> `./dump/dbName/"$i".bson`

**Note :** MongoDB `v3.2` is so old & in cloud based MongoDB service [Mongo-atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) it has already reached it's end of lifecycle, So please upgrade asap. If you're looking for a free mongo instance or starting with MongoDB - you can try atlas.

Answer (score 0):

> `db.cloneCollection()` copies data directly between MongoDB **instances**.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/

That means you cannot clone inside the same mongod instance. Use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html) and [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoimport/) to clone your collection.

---

Since 4.2 MongoDb introduces [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#comparison-with-out) operator which allows copy from `db1.collection` to `db2.collection`.