# How do I copy all data from one Mongodb Cloud Project to another?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have two projects on cloud.mongodb.com. One for staging, another - for prodution.

I need to quickly synchronize staging with production for debugging. Just erase everything on the staging and fill it with production data. How do I do that?

Trying mongomirror, but it seems require for cluster tiers to be the same. I want to keep using free tier on staging and whateve larger tier on produciton.

Comment: what is your data size, what if you do it by shell script using mongoexport & mongoimport iterating over collections ?

Comment: 100mb. Thanks, i'll try mongoexport & mongoimport.

Comment: you can actually try this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133931/how-to-clone-a-collection-from-one-mongodb-to-another-on-same-server/60139892#60139892

Answer (score 7):

Now days in Mongo Atlas you can use the `Restore` function between two different projects and/or clusters.

Inside mongodb atlas, go to your chosen source cluster, choose "Backup", then select the snapshot you want and click restore, then choose the destination project and cluster you want to restore to, mongo atlas does the rest.[image: restoring]

Answer (score 1):

Install mongodb tools:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

Download all data:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@<full uri with all replicas>/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=<cluster-name>&authSource=admin"
```

```
mongorestore --uri="<the same kind of uri>" <directory or file to restore>
```