# Cloud Atlas MongoDB - clone a collection to a new collection

Tags: mongodb-atlas

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133931/how-to-clone-a-collection-from-one-mongodb-to-another-on-same-server), but specific to using the web interface at cloud.mongodb.com.

Is is possible to clone a large collection using the website?  Or do I have to use a command line interface?

Also, if I click "restore" from a backup, will it prompt for a collection name?  I was afraid to hit it because I didn't know if it would immediately start restoring, or give me some options first.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way in Atlas, so I used MongoDB Compass, which meant I had to export the collection to file and then import it into another database

Comment: But how this helps the OP who looks for a MongoDB solution?